# How to recalculate the values in textboxes in VBA userforms?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating sample text boxes A , B , C , D  and E.

C = A + B

D = A/C

E = B/C

Is there a way where I can get the changed values in A and B when I change the values in D and E manually ??

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code in your userform:

```
Private Sub D_Change()
   On error resume next
   A = cdbl(D)*cdbl(C)
   B = cdbl(E)*cdbl(C)
end sub

Private Sub E_Change()
   on error resume next
   A = cdbl(D)*cdbl(C)
   B = cdbl(E)*cdbl(C)
end sub
```

Comment: If i do that, i am getting the following error :  "Run time error '13 ; Type mismatch"

Comment: It should now work. String values in the textbox are now converted to Double. Invalid entries (like letters) will not cause errors thanks to the resume next.